# iOS - Setting lineJoinStyle to .round for UIBezierpath does not work (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

My code is this:

```
let myPath = UIBezierPath()
myPath.lineJoinStyle = .round
let rect = bounds
myPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.05, y: rect.midY))
myPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX / 3, y: rect.maxY / 10),
                controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: rect.midX/5, y: rect.midY/2),
                controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: rect.midX/3, y: rect.midY/3))
myPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 2/3, y: rect.maxY / 5),
                    controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.6, y: rect.maxY / 4))
```

But still first and second curves joint point is not round. What should I do to make it round and smooth?

Here is result image:

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Can you please tell what output you are expecting...?

Comment: I am expecting joint points to be more smooth and round, something like this: https://prnt.sc/sgmyp6 

But I guess it should be achieved by changing control points to match the slopes of lines.

Comment: Working on this...Will add answer soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here As per your expectation [https://prnt.sc/sgmyp6](http://expectation) i have used `addQuadCurve` function to make a curve.

took a `UIView` with `Height = 200` And `Width = 300`

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerView: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let centerViewW = centerView.frame.size.width. //Width Of your view
        let centerViewH = centerView.frame.size.height //Height Of your view

        let myPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        let drawingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        drawingLayer.strokeColor =  UIColor.red.cgColor
        drawingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        drawingLayer.lineWidth = 4.0

        //This is starting point from where you start drawing
        myPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: centerViewH-25))

        //This is First Curve
        myPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ((centerViewW/2)+10), y: (centerViewH/3+15)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 20))

        drawingLayer.path = myPath.cgPath
        centerView.layer.addSublayer(drawingLayer)

        //This is Second Curve
        myPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerViewW, y: (centerViewH/2)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (centerViewW - 45), y: (centerViewH/2)+40))

        drawingLayer.path = myPath.cgPath
        centerView.layer.addSublayer(drawingLayer)
}
```

You just have to update/change the control points to match the slopes of lines.

Output:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks Saifan. Works fine, This is the result I was expecting. So it is all about control points and slopes of two lines to match each other.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: welcome GShukakidze, try to make different types of curve's so that you'll understand how control point works.....